# Saving more than one scalar to TensorBoard

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard, eager-execution

I am on Eager Mode, and I am trying to plot the evolution of some scalars in TensorBoard. 
I have managed to do it for one - the loss function - by using:

```
        summary_writer = tf.contrib.summary.create_file_writer(log_dir, flush_millis=10000)
        with summary_writer.as_default(), tf.contrib.summary.always_record_summaries():
        tf.contrib.summary.scalar("loss", curr_loss)
```

However, if I add another line of code with

```
        tf.contrib.summary.scalar("phi", phi)
```

then it does not get recorded (or at least it does not show up in TensorBoard). I couldn't find many references for this, but the ones I did find made me write it like this...

Does anyone know how to do this properly? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you follow the [guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/summaries_and_tensorboard) closely you will have 3 crutial steps to get your summary written:
1. Create summaries

```
phi_summary_op = tf.contrib.summary.scalar("phi", phi)
```

1.2. (optional) Collect all summaries in one operations

```
merged = tf.summary.merge_all()
```

2. Execute summary op in your session along with traing (or validation) step:

```
summary, _ = sess.run([merged, train_step], feed_dict=feed_dict(True))
```

3. Write the result into corresponding log file:

```
train_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(FLAGS.summaries_dir + '/train',
                                      sess.graph)
train_writer.add_summary(summary, i)
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that I am using eager mode. I cannot use sess or tf.summary.FileWriter. This is why I am using tf.contrib.summary.create_file_writer to write the summary.

Comment: @python_enthusiast did you try summary_writer.flush() asfter call to scalar(...) ?

Comment: I tried it now (didn't know it existed, to be honest). I am running         tf.contrib.summary.scalar("loss", curr_loss)
        tf.contrib.summary.scalar("phi", self.phi)
        tf.contrib.summary.merge_all()
        tf.contrib.summary.flush(). But it does not work yet.

Comment: Than I would also check 1) your tensorboad script points to the folder with log files 2) log files changes size when training is running

Comment: For (1) it does because when I run the code I get a new plot for the loss function on TensorBoard. For (2) I don't know how to check. But I think I have found what the problem is. My phi is not a tensor like the loss function is. It is just a constant. I will try changing this to see if it works.

Comment: It worked! Thank you for your help. Sorry, I am new to Tensorflow =)

Comment: We all've been there, no worries)